# Clearing All The Panel Values

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have A Panel Where user input Strings in text box and Decimal numbers in Number counter and checkboxes when the user save the info or click the back button i want all the values to go back to default if it was a new form case it would do that automaticly but in panels i saw controls.clear but it remove all the panel textboxes and stuff any way to just create a new instance clear them by anyway ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Controls Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt340bh4.aspx) to clear all controls, without having to name them all:

```
foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
{
    TextBox       t = (c as TextBox);
    NumericUpDown n = (c as NumericUpDown);

    if (t != null)
        t.Text = "";

    if (n != null)
        n.Value = 0;
}
```

You would need to use multiple for-loops or recursion to handle child controls.

Comment: I am doing a function to do this but its showing me error at page.controls what u mean by page? i tried to change it to my form name but didn't work

Comment: this . controls worked but not on checked box i declared 
Checkbox cb = (c as Checkbox);
if (cb.Checked)
cb.Checked=false; but its giving me null exception i have 4 checkboxes and some might be checked some not im checking with this if it is checked or not tho why would it give me null ?

Comment: It will be null for controls which are not Checkboxes. if (cb != null && cb.Checked) cb.Checked = false;

Comment: hmm i tried to clear all without checkbox same codes u said but it didnt do anything

Answer (score 0):

Panels.Clear(); would remove all of the child controls within the Panel container. What you would normally do is either manually set the default values of the controls you wish to go back to defaults, or alternatively you could iterate through the controls and reset them.

Personally I prefer the manual approach in a situation where there are multiple types of controls to reset, otherwise you could run into some issues.

So just as an example:

```
Textbox.Text = ""; 
Textbox.Text = string.Empty; 
Textbox.Text.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a method that removes all the controls from the panel.

Instead, you should write a method in your Form that sets each of the values in the panel's controls to an appropriate default. Set the textbox values to empty strings, the numeric updowns to 0.0, etc. Name that method `ClearPanelValues()` or something. Then call `ClearPanelControls()` when you want to clear the values in the panel.

```
public void ClearPanelValues()
{
    textBox1.Text = "";
    textBox2.Text = "";
    numericUpDown1.Value = 0;
    // etc. etc. 
}
```